# Animation on AVPlayerViewController not synchronized

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation, avplayerviewcontroller, avplayerlayer

I have a `AVPlayerViewController` that I create in this way:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"testURL"];
    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];
    AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [AVPlayerViewController new];

    playerViewController.player = player;
    [playerViewController.player play];
    [playerViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)];

    [self.view addSubview:playerViewController.view];
    [self addChildViewController:playerViewController];

int width = 100;
int height = 150;
int xPosition = self.view.frame.size.width - width;
int yPosition = 100;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
playerViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(xPosition, yPosition, width, height);
[UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

My problem is that in this way I get this:

> the playerViewController.view's animation is not synchronized with the
>   video and the playerViewController.view slowly reduces while the video
>   is immediately reduced.

I don't understand why.

if you need it I can link a video of what I get